# "No module named bs4(BeautifulSoup) Azure"

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage

I am quite new to Azure. I have problems deploying my web app to azure. The following are the logs when i deploy.

```
2018-10-09T14:04:05    /home/site/wwwroot
2018-10-09T14:04:05    Found requirements.txt
2018-10-09T14:04:05    Create virtual environment
2018-10-09T14:04:09    Activate virtual environment
2018-10-09T14:04:15    Collecting beautifulsoup4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
2018-10-09T14:04:15      Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/21/0a/47fdf541c97fd9b6a610cb5fd518175308a7cc60569962e776ac52420387/beautifulsoup4-4.6.3-py3-none-any.whl
2018-10-09T14:04:15    Collecting PyPDF2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
2018-10-09T14:04:15      Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b4/01/68fcc0d43daf4c6bdbc6b33cc3f77bda531c86b174cac56ef0ffdb96faab/PyPDF2-1.26.0.tar.gz
2018-10-09T14:04:16    Collecting requests (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
2018-10-09T14:04:17      Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/65/47/7e02164a2a3db50ed6d8a6ab1d6d60b69c4c3fdf57a284257925dfc12bda/requests-2.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
2018-10-09T14:04:17    Collecting azure-storage (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
2018-10-09T14:04:17      Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/76/26/482c033f8f3a48d16cf75aad91c3e1256856719f4117fabb4696d33aa5da/azure_storage-0.36.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
2018-10-09T14:04:17    Collecting json (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
2018-10-09T14:04:17      Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement json (from -r requirements.txt (line 5)) (from versions: )
2018-10-09T14:04:17    No matching distribution found for json (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
2018-10-09T14:04:17    You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 18.1 is available.
2018-10-09T14:04:17    You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
2018-10-09T14:04:17    pip install finished
2018-10-09T14:04:17    Finished successfully.
2018-10-09T14:04:18  Running post deployment command(s)...
2018-10-09T14:04:18  Deployment successful.
2018-10-09T14:04:19  App container will begin restart within 10 seconds.

2018-10-09T14:04:31.926761435Z [2018-10-09 14:04:31 +0000] [38] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2018-10-09T14:04:31.926782635Z Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-10-09T14:04:31.926798836Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2018-10-09T14:04:31.926807236Z     worker.init_process()
2018-10-09T14:04:31.926811736Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
2018-10-09T14:04:31.926816736Z     self.load_wsgi()
2018-10-09T14:04:31.926821037Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
2018-10-09T14:04:31.926833137Z     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2018-10-09T14:04:31.926837937Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2018-10-09T14:04:31.926842337Z     self.callable = self.load()
2018-10-09T14:04:31.926846537Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
2018-10-09T14:04:31.926851038Z     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2018-10-09T14:04:31.926855238Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
2018-10-09T14:04:31.926859638Z     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2018-10-09T14:04:31.926863938Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
2018-10-09T14:04:31.926868438Z     __import__(module)
2018-10-09T14:04:31.926933340Z   File "/home/site/wwwroot/application.py", line 2, in <module>
2018-10-09T14:04:31.926943041Z     from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
2018-10-09T14:04:31.926947341Z ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'
```

Beautifulsoup seems to install initially but when i make a request it throws an error. I am not able to import other popular libraries as well. Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

You'd better provide more details, like the requirements.txt and which os you are working on.

I write a simple code which includes the Beautifulsoup4 (my environment is windows 10), and it can works well. I think you can use it at your side for a testing purpose to make sure if Beautifulsoup4 works or not.

Most of the steps are following this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-python).

Steps as below:

1.In git bash:
first execute `git clone https://github.com/Azure-Samples/python-docs-hello-world`,

then execute `cd python-docs-hello-world`

2.Modify the application.py file by adding Beautifulsoup4, code as below:

```
  from flask import Flask
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

  app = Flask(__name__)

  @app.route("/")
  def hello():
      soup = BeautifulSoup("<p>it is a bs4 testing</p>")
      return soup.prettify()
```

3.Modify the requirements.txt by adding Beautifulsoup4:

```
click==6.7
Flask==1.0.2
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.10
MarkupSafe==1.0
Werkzeug==0.14.1
beautifulsoup4==4.6.3
```

4.in git bash, do the following command one by one:

```
py -3 -m venv venv
venv/scripts/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
FLASK_APP=application.py flask run
```

Open a web browser, and navigate to the sample app at http://localhost:5000/ .

It is to make sure it can work well in local.

5.Then just follow the [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-python) to create deployment credetial / resource group / service plan / a web app

6.If no issues, in git bash, push the code to azure:

```
git remote add azure <deploymentLocalGitUrl-from-create-step>
```

then `git push azure master`, the output as below:
[image]

7.Browse to the website like http://.azurewebsites.net, bs4 works well:
[image]

Comment: I took the same code (include requirements.txt) and redeployed after deleting the original deployment it worked properly. I am using Linux OS. Idk why that happened. Probably since I was using free version.

Comment: the free trial subscription for azure?

Comment: Yeah student version

Comment: @yatishhr,  I think you can use my code to test if the issue is due to the free version.